# looking for a glossary of terms

Tags: support

Is there a stackexchange glossary somewhere. I still haven't figured out what OP stands for and I probably have some other definitions wrong but I don't know it yet.

Comment: [This](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3012/common-acronyms-used-on-main-and-meta) should take you some part of the way.